# Calculation of the sum of Self Powers

Tags: java

The series, `1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 10^10 = 10405071317`, where `^` here denotes "to the power of".

Find the last ten digits of the series, `1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 1000^1000`.

```
BigInteger sum=BigInteger.ZERO;
for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
    long pow=(long)Math.pow(i, i);
    sum=sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(pow));
    System.out.println(sum);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

This does not give the desired result. Can anyone point out the mistake?

Comment: Well, `1000^1000` is far too big for a `long` (where by `^` I mean "to the power of").  You need to use `BigInteger` for each of the individual powers.

Comment: The title of the question, the wording of the question, and the first equality, show that he/she clearly MEANT to write powers (that is, the sum is 1 + 4 + 27 + 256 etc), but simply didn't know the best way to show it in the question.  I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: This is Problem 48 from Project Euler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **could** use [`BigInteger.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int)) to calculate each exponential term. However, a better approach is to note that you only need the last 10 digits of the final result. You can use the `%` operator to help simplify this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger count = new BigInteger("1");
for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){
    BigInteger pow = count.pow(i);
    sum = sum.add(pow);
    System.out.println(sum);
    count = count.add(one);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

You actually made me think about this. It was difficult. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem in your code is that you're doing all of the calculating of the exponents in `Math.pow`, which only works with doubles.

```
BigInteger sum=BigInteger.ZERO;
for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
    long pow=(long)Math.pow(i, i); // <-- All of the exponents calculated here
    sum=sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(pow)); // <-- Converted to BigInteger *after*
    System.out.println(sum);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Quoting the docs for [`Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) (emphasis mine):

> - If both arguments are integers, then the result is exactly equal to the mathematical result of raising the first argument to the power of the second argument **if that result can in fact be represented exactly as a double value.**

The largest number that can be represented with a double is roughly ~10<sup>308</sup>, so by the time you got 150 terms in, none of those `Math.pow(i,i)` calls would've returned the correct value.

---

Since this *is* Project Euler, I'm not going to post a full fix, but needless to say, if you plan on actually calculating each of those terms, you need to be doing the arithmetic operations on BigIntegers directly.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to the other fellas responses but shorter:

```
static String q48(){
    BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("1");
    for(int i=2;i<=1000;i++)
        sum = sum.add(new BigInteger(i+"").pow(i));
    return sum.toString().substring(sum.toString().length()-10);
}

// 9110846700
```